# How to prevent archiving and search engine caching in a free Wordpress blog?

Tags: archives, cache, blog

I don't like to have my free Wordpress blog cached by search engines or even worse, archived by the known archiving websites and services like The Wayback Machine. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you could do.

**Use the built in Search Engine Visibility setting**

Access WordPress admin area and go to Settings > select Reading > Search Engine Visibility

Check the box that says Discourage search engines from indexing this site. After enabling it, WordPress will edit the robots.txt file and apply disallow rules which discourage search engines from crawling and indexing your site.

**Manually Edit robots.text**

You can manually edit robots.txt in the root of your site and add the following code.

```
User-agent:     *
Disallow: /
```

**Password Protection**

If you don't have a public site you could password protect it.  This is the only guaranteed way to make sure your site does not get indexed.  There are a ton of plugins that will do this, [here is the one I normally use](https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-my-site/).

**Removing your site for Google Search**

If you website has already been indexed by Google, you can follow these steps to get it removed.

1. You will need to create an account with [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools).
2. Log in to your Google Webmaster Tools account.
3. If the account is new, you will have to add your web site.
4. Click the "Add a site" button.
5. Enter your web site URL and click "Continue"
6. Now you need to access the web site [removal tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals).
7. Once you have opened the web site removal tool, click on "New Removal Request".
8. On the 'Create a new request' page, select the options that match your removal request, fill in the required fields and then click the Submit Request button